# \includegraphics compiling only when in local folder

Tags: includegraphics

I just a massive update of my MikTeX in the university computer (previous version was from 2014).

I always work in a way that I can access my files from any machine connected to the university network, but after the update I found that I can compile **\includegraphics** only if the picture is saved on the local folder (which I recall with **\graphicspath**).

This is not a terrible problem but still annoying (I depend more on one machine and I have to be more careful not to lose the pictures). Do you have any idea how I can fix this issue?

An example of code is:

```
\documentclass[svgnames,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
x
\graphicspath{{C:/.../documents/Pictures/}}
\includegraphics[width=10cm]{heisball44.jpg}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved (apparently)!

I write it here for others to read and because I didn't find an answer elsewhere. It was extremely trivial, I just had to add **./** to the picture (somehow adding the full location didn't work).

```
\includegraphics[width=10cm]{./heisball44.jpg}
```